# Why sometimes I use | and sometimes || for "or" in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I want to check if `x` is `NaN` or `inf`. If it is, i replace it with 1.

```
if isnan(x) || isinf(x)
    x = 1;
end
```

vs

```
x(isnan(x)|isinf(x)) = 1;
```

Are they both correct in expressing "or"? It seems that they both work but I am unsure and I don't know why  sometimes I use | and sometimes || for "or" in MATLAB?

Comment: Usually `||` is logical OR and `|` is bitwise OR. Perhaps you should [read up on the operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/matlab/matlab_operators.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` and `|` operators don't do what you think they do. Think of them more as "intersection" and "union" operators for binary masks (i.e. element-wise logical `and` and logical `or` operations for logical arrays).

Perhaps it's best to illustrate with an example:

```
>> A = zeros(10,10); A(2:6,2:6) = 1;
>> B = zeros(10,10); B(4:8,4:8) = 1;
>> subplot(1,3,1); imagesc(A+B); axis image off; title('A + B', 'fontsize', 20);
>> subplot(1,3,2); imagesc(A&B); axis image off; title('A & B', 'fontsize', 20);
>> subplot(1,3,3); imagesc(A|B); axis image off; title('A | B', 'fontsize', 20);
```

[image]

In other words, these are normal operators that operate on logical *arrays*.

In contrast, `&&` and `||` are programming constructs, known as *shortcut operators*, designed to evaluate *statements*. `&&` evaluates to `true` if two statements are *both* true, and `||` evaluates to `true` if *either* of them is true. The reason they are called *shortcut* operators is that they serve a programmatic function of **not evaluating the right-hand-side operand, if the logical evaluation of the left-hand-side guarantees the expression's outcome regardless of the right-hand-side**. As such, their inputs need to be *logical expressions*, i.e. something that evaluates to a *logical scalar* value of 1 or 0 (i.e. `true` or `false`).

This is incredibly useful for evaluating constraints that would lead to errors if evaluated, e.g. division by zero or undefined variables, e.g.:

```
>> condition1 = exist('MyVar') && MyVar == 0 % no error
condition1 =
     0

>> condition2 = exist('MyVar') & MyVar == 0  % error
Undefined function or variable 'MyVar'.
```

An `if` block is designed to evaluate logical *statements*. i.e. "if statement *x* is logically true then do *y*". Therefore you should be using shortcut operators, not logical arrays.

The `if` keyword *happens* to be overloaded for arrays (i.e. `if [1,1]; disp(1); end` will work) but this is only for syntactic convenience, and for more rigorous programming you should really be explicit what the resulting logical expression should be (e.g. `if all([1,1]); disp(1); end`).

Also, note that while `if` is overloaded, `assert` isn't, so `assert([1,1])` will result in an error, because `[1,1]` does not evaluate to `true` (i.e. a scalar logical value of 1). If you tried to use `&` and `|` in the context of `assert` you'd probably mess it up.

Comment: PS. As for your second example, you are performing logical indexing there. To answer the "are they always the same" if your `x` variable isn't a scalar, then no, they will not give the same result.

Answer (score 8):

They are not quite the same. The right hand argument of `||` is not evaluated if the result of the left hand side is sufficient to yield the answer. This is called *short-circuitting* and also applies to `&&`.

For `|`, both arguments are always evaluated.

Furthermore, `||` returns a straightforward 1 or 0 (true or false).

But `|` computes a *bitwise* OR, so the result is subtly different. For the corresponding `&` operator this can even be pernicious: For example if the left hand side returns binary `0b01` and the right hand side binary `0b10` then, although both arguments are non-zero, the result of the expression *is* zero.

In your case, use `if isnan(x) || isinf(x)`

Comment: Thanks. Is the result the same if I want to perform my task: Check if x is NaN or inf. If it is, i replace it with 1. Will the second method sometimes give wrong answer?

Comment: Not in this case no. But I'd always use `||` *unless* you need to bitwise logical answer.

Comment: `|` computes an [element-wise zero-or-nonzero comparison](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html#description) between its arguments; [`bitor`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bitor.html) is the function for a true bit-wise `or`-ing of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that when you use exp1 | exp2 both expressions are evaluated and only then | is performed, while when you use exp1 || exp2, exp2 will be evaluated only when exp1 is false.